# Express wrong static path react lazy

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I have express ssr app. I want to host my static files in /static/* folder. But i have problem with React.Lazy component chunk request, it has wrong path

```
http://localhost:3000/staticreact.LazyChunk.js
```

My server code:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';

import handleRequest from '@server/infrastructure/handleRequest/handleRequest';
import {routes} from '@general-infrastructure/routes/routes';
import { handleErrors } from '@server/middlewares/errorHandler/errorHandler';

const server = express();

// if i'll comment this, reactlazy chunk will have normal path, but other static files will have 404 error status

server.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/static')));

// TODO -
// 5. redux for theme

server.get('*', handleErrors(async function(req, res, next) {
    handleRequest(req.url, res, routes);
}));

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server running on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

if i'll comment server.use , reactlazy chunk will have normal path, but other static files will have 404 error status.

How can i fix it? ty

Noone extra slash not working

Webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'client',
    entry: {
        client: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/index.tsx'),
    },
    mode: mode,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/dist/static'),
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
        publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '/static'),
        chunkFilename: 'react.[name].chunk.js',
        clean: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss'],
        alias: webpackAliases,
    },
```

Noone extra slash in webpack config not working

Router:

```
const Lazy = React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "LazyChunk" */ '@client/modules/pages/Lazy'));

const Routes: React.FC = () => {
    const AppRoutes =  useRoutes(
        [
            {path: '/', element: <Feed />},
            {path: '/lazy', element: <Lazy />},
            {path: '/overview', element: <Overview.component />},
        ],
    );
    return (
        <Suspense fallback="Loading...">
            {AppRoutes}
        </Suspense>
    );
};
```

React lazy load chunk error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[publicPath](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpublicpath)

> the value of this option ends with /

Try adding `/`

```
publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '/static') + '/',
```

Comment: You can also try `publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '/static/')` - looks better, but I'm not sure if it works

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work i lost hope

Answer (score 0):

try to use only this,
`server.use(express.static("/static"));`

Comment: It's works only for react lazy component, others has 404 error with right path

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please "edit" to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer